# SSRS 2008 R2 split column /into 3 valuesd

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

In an SSRS 2008 existing report, I have one column that I need to separate the values. I am not allowed to change the database. I am told that I need to work with the data as it is.

The values in the column look like the following

099 11-12 Midwest Plumbers.

I need to split the data to look like

1. 099 is the Customer Number.
2. 11-12 is the year the customer data was valid.
3. Midwest Plumbers is the name of the company.

Notes:

1. The delimiter between the 3 fields is " " (one space).
2. The company name can contain lots of spaces.
3. There are 3 fields that need to be separated out which are:

a. Customer Number,

b. Effective Years,

c. Customer Name.

I 'best' solution, I have so far is:

=Mid(Parameters!pCust.Value,InStr(Parameters!pCust.Value," ") + 1,Len(Parameters!pCust.Value)-Instr(Parameters!pCust.Value," ")).

However the above only gets me the first value.

Thus can you show me how to split up the in this column within SSRS?

Answer (score 1):

First String

```
=Split(Parameters!pCust.Value," ").GetValue(0)
```

Second String

```
=Split(Parameters!pCust.Value," ").GetValue(1)
```

Third string

```
=Split(Parameters!pCust.Value," ").GetValue(2)
```

Comment: You are basically are saying that I execute these 3 statements in role and it be able to obtain the field values I want?

Comment: Yes these are the expressions you need to get the values you need.